# Python subprocess.call - adding a variable to subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess, windowserror

I'm trying to write a simple program in Python that takes all the music files from my Downloads folder and puts them in my Music folder. I'm using Windows, and I can move the files using the cmd prompt, but I get this error:

`WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os 
from subprocess import call

def main():
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\Alex\Downloads") #change directory to downloads folder

    suffix =".mp3"    #variable holdinng the .mp3 tag
    fnames = os.listdir('.')  #looks at all files

    files =[]  #an empty array that will hold the names of our mp3 files

    for fname in fnames:  
        if fname.endswith(suffix):
            pname = os.path.abspath(fname)
            #pname = fname
            #print pname

            files.append(pname)  #add the mp3 files to our array
    print files

    for i in files:
        #print i 
        move(i)

def move(fileName):
    call("move /-y "+ fileName +" C:\Music")
    return

if __name__=='__main__':main()
```

I've looked at the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) library and countless other articles, but I still have no clue what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Does not your `fileName` contain spaces? If it does, you have to use `'"' + fileName + '"'` instead, or `move` won't find the file.

Comment: On a sidenote, these aren't arrays, but lists

Comment: What is the problem with `[os.rename](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename)`

Answer (score 7):

The `subprocess.call` method taks a list of parameters not a string with space separators unless you tell it to use the shell which is not recommended if the string can contain anything from user input.

The best way is to build the command as a list

e.g.

```
cmd = ["move", "/-y", fileName, "C:\Music"]
call(cmd)
```

this also makes it easier to pass parameters (e.g. paths or files) with spaces in to the called program.

Both these ways are given in the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

You can pass in a delimited string but then you have to let the shell process the arguments

```
call("move /-y "+ fileName +" C:\Music", shell=True)
```

Also in this case for move there is a python command to do this. `shutil.move`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not answering your question directly, but for such tasks, [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is great and  would make your life so much easier. `subprocess`'s api is not very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issues:

1. `fileName` might contain a space in it so the `move` command only sees a part of filename.
2. if `move` is an internal command; you might need `shell=True` to run it:

```py
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(r"move /-y C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\*.mp3 C:\Music", shell=True)
```

To move `.mp3` files from Downloads folder to Music without `subprocess`:

```py
from glob import glob
from shutil import move

for path in glob(r"C:\Users\Alex\Downloads\*.mp3"):
    move(path, r"C:\Music")
```